# Highcharts.js - Switch label axis and hiding legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been looking for a decent chart based solution for websites and I think HighCharts looks like it fits the bill. The documentation seems pretty good but there are a few weird things it's doing that I need some help with.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/T78R9/

- I have selected 6 labels but there the plugin is outputting 7
  markers.
- I'm trying to display the labels on the x-axis only with
  nothing on the y-axis but the chart is outputting the labels on the
  y-axis and not displaying the labels on the x-axis.
- Is there a way to hide the legend? I can't find this option.

Code Below:

```
$(function () { 
     $('#chart-data').highcharts({
          chart: {
                type: 'bar'
          },
          title: {
                text: ''
          },
          xAxis: {
                categories: ['Pre-Clinical', 'Phase I', 'Phase II', 'Phase III', 'Phase IV', 'Launch',]
          },
          yAxis: {

          },
          plotOptions: {
                line: {
                     dataLabels: {
                          enabled: true,
                          align: 'top'
                     },
                     enableMouseTracking: false
                }
          },                
          series: [{
                name: 'AMG 319',
                data: [6, 0, 0, 0, 0]
          }, {
                name: 'BAY 80-6946',
                data: [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
          }, {
                name: 'GDC-0980 (RG7422)',
                data: [0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
          }, {
               name: 'Buparlisib (BKM120)',
               data: [0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
          }, {
               name: 'CUDC-907',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
          }, {
               name: 'GDC-09',
                data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
          }]
     });
});
```

Comment: First and second point are not clear for me. Have you started with [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/understanding-highcharts)? For example what do you mean by "I selected 6 labels"? Which labels?

Comment: These labels: categories: ['Pre-Clinical', 'Phase I', 'Phase II', 'Phase III', 'Phase IV', 'Launch',]

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/T78R9/10/ - note that categories are 0-based, to value = 4 will mean 'Phase IV'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In order as asked:**

- The Categories do not determine the number of labels, only the content.  If the data exceeds the number of categories, any additional points will be labelled numerically.  To specify an x value corresponding to a category label, use the category array index (starting from 0) as the x value.
- In a horizontal bar chart, the x and y axes are swapped - they literally just turn a column chart on its side.
- you can set '`enabled: false`' for the legend: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.enabled

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! One more question, do you know how to disable increments? I want the chart to show numbers 1-6 without any in between numbers.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the 'allowDecimals' property - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.allowDecimals

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why these things aren't working for you, but there is a legend enabled: false to hide legend, same with labels. But I wonder if you are confused about x/y axis since this is a bar chart and not a column chart. As far as your 6 vs 7 labels, I again believe it is the orientation confusing you and you have not specified labels for both axes, so Highcharts is making the labels for the unspecified axis, using the data you gave.
Check this out, done real quick but hopefully helps:
   http://jsfiddle.net/T78R9/7/

```
// HighCharts Plugin
$(function () { 
 $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
            type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
            text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
          labels: {enabled:false},
            categories: ['Pre-Clinical', 'Phase I', 'Phase II', 'Phase III', 'Phase IV', 'Launch',]
      },
      yAxis: {

      },
      plotOptions: {
            line: {
                 dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true,
                      align: 'top'
                 },
                 enableMouseTracking: false
            }
      },                
      series: [{
            name: 'AMG 319',
            data: [6, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      }, {
            name: 'BAY 80-6946',
            data: [0, 5, 0, 0, 0]
      }, {
            name: 'GDC-0980 (RG7422)',
            data: [0, 0, 4, 0, 0]
      }, {
           name: 'Buparlisib (BKM120)',
           data: [0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
      }, {
           name: 'CUDC-907',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
      }, {
           name: 'GDC-09',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
      }],
                            legend: { enabled: false}                      
 });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am actually looking to have the horizontal bars. See the design for what I'm trying to achieve: http://s4.postimg.org/f2bew906l/Screen_Shot_2014_01_24_at_17_00_14.png

Thank you for displaying the code for removing the legend. I still need to remove the y-axis labels and display the categories inside the bars. Any ideas?